# Link axes in Makie.jl if other plot elements present

Tags: plot, julia, makie.jl

I would like to create multiple subplots with their own individual legends and shared y-axis limits. I am currently creating the subplots in a loop by doing the following:

```
fig = Figure()
    
for i in 1:3
    lines(fig[i, 1], rand(10), label="$i")
end
    
linkyaxes!(fig.content...)
    
fig
```

This works fine, but when attempting to add a legend to each subplot next:

```
fig = Figure()
    
for i in 1:3
    lines(fig[i, 1], rand(10), label="$i")
    axislegend()
end
    
linkyaxes!(fig.content...)
    
fig
```

this now throws an error:

```
MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type Makie.MakieLayout.Legend to an object of type Makie.MakieLayout.Axis
```

because `fig.content` now includes `Makie.MakieLayout.Legend()` objects, in addition to the original `Axis` objects from before.

Do I need to filter these out beforehand, or is there a better way to produce the desired plots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the best approach, but you could ensure that you pass the axes to `linkyaxes!` this way:

```
axs = []

fig = Figure()

for i in 1:3
    ax = lines(fig[i, 1], rand(10), label="$i").axis
    push!(axs, ax)
    axislegend()
end

linkyaxes!(axs...)
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about `.axis`, thanks Benoit!

Comment: When you invoke a function as `plot_func(::GridPosition, ...)`, it returns an `AxisPlot` which is basically a container for an axis and whichever plot `plot_func` created.  For full versatility you can capture both as `ax, plt = lines(...)`.